# Problem on Real Numbers

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

I am quite amazed how can I prove the following known idea using Real Analysis

$$x^{2}\ge0$$ for any real number x. Also $$1\gt0$$ and if n is a natural number then $$ n\gt0$$.

Answer (score 1):

proof of $x^{2}\ge0$: 
  case 1: Let $x\ge0$ So $x^{2}\ge0$
   case 2 : Let $x\le0$ => $-x\ge0$ So $x^{2}\ge0$
    case 3 : If x=0 then $x^2\ge0$

### Answer of 2nd parts

natural numbers are greater then zero by definition . So if n is a natural number then $ n\ge0$

Comment: thanks @waytoinfinity i think -x>0 will not imply x>0

Comment: $-x\ge0$ By squaring both side we get $x^2\ge0$

Comment: The error is corrected .

Comment: yuph, thanks @waytoinfinity...

Comment: also: $1>0$ because $1=1^2$ and $1\neq0$. And by induction we get $n+1 > 0$.